Mongoose and typescript: Using values from a populated field who has a union type
I have these models:

CoupleModel.ts

import mongoose, { Model,Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { CoupleType } from '../types/coupleTypes';

const coupleSchema = new Schema(
    {
        user1: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
        user2: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

export default coupleSchema;
const Couple: Model<CoupleType> = mongoose.model<CoupleType>('Couple', coupleSchema);


UserModel.ts

   import mongoose, { Model,Schema } from 'mongoose';
    import { UserType } from '../types/userTypes';
    
    const userSchema = new Schema(
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                match: [/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/, 'Please use a valid email address.'],
            },
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
        }
    );
    
    const User: Model<UserType> = mongoose.model<UserType>('User', userSchema);
    
    export default User;

I have these types definitions:

userType.ts

import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type UserType = Document & {
    name: string;
    email: string;
};


coupleType.ts

import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { UserType } from './userTypes';
export type CoupleType = Document & {
    user1: Types.ObjectId | UserType;
    user2: Types.ObjectId | UserType;
};

The reason I defined user1 and user2 with the type Types.ObjectId | UserType is because depending on the operation, they can be either of those:

If it's couple.find(), they will be of type Types.ObjectId
If it's couple.find().populate(['user1','user2'], they will be of type UserType
In the couple.create({user1,user2}), they will be of type Types.ObjectId


Now this is my problem:
  const couples = await Couple.find().populate('user1').populate('user2');

    const emailPromises = couples.map(async (couple) => {
      const { user1, user2 } = couple;
      console.log(" ~ emailPromises ~ user1.email:", user1.email)
      console.log(" ~ emailPromises ~ user2.email:", user2.email)
    });

Typescript will not automatically infer the type of user1 and user2 as type UserType.
So it will throw this error:
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'ObjectId | UserType'.
  Property 'email' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'.ts(2339)

What should I do?

I decided to use typeguard:
export const isUserType = (user: Types.ObjectId | UserType): user is UserType => {
    return (user as UserType).email !== undefined;
}


  if (user1 && isUserType(user1)) {
  }

I could have used type casting:
  const user1 = couple.user1 as UserType;

But, this is a riskier approach as it could cause a runtime error in case something goes wrong with populate for example and what's returned ends up not following the structure of UserType.
